# What percentage of the brain is memory | Storage of thoughts, episodes

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurophysiology, memory

I was reading the [article](https://www.cnsnevada.com/what-is-the-memory-capacity-of-a-human-brain/), in which it is mentioned that human brain constitutes 2.5 petabytes of memory. This made me wonder how much of the brain is associated with memory itself. If we categorize brain by functionality, such as dedicated areas for visual processing, audible processing, logic processing, memory storage etc, what percentage of the brain is utilized for memory itself?

I speculate that the brain does more memory related tasks then any other. As a matter of fact, almost all tasks for humans requires memory, so perhaps 70-80% of brain might be just to store memory. Is this correct? If not then what percentage of the brain is used for storing memories?

Comment: All of it depending on how you define memory.

Comment: @John could you please elaborate. Memory is defined as "storage" of any abstract object such as past events, thoughts, dreams ..etc

Comment: everything you brain does is memory, learning how to interpret sense organ signals, muscle movement, etc is all memory.

Comment: @John, what about reasoning, cognition, they do indeed differ from memory, althought they utilize memory but I believe the part of the brain that deals with reasoning, cognition, emotions, are not memory themselves.

Comment: They are all memory, they learn patterns.

Comment: @John its quite hard for me to reason that how is cognition and emotion are memories. Cognition is related to attention and learning endavour, which utilizes memories to keep track of the learned stuff but how come they themselves are memories?

Comment: they are learned skills, thus memories. even emotions are plastic meaning their associations can be altered by learning.

Comment: @John alright i understood your point after reading the answer below :) so overtime memory shapes the 'function' that gives rises to emotion and it changes. So this function itself is plastic in nature. I somehow wanted to separate these so-called learned functions from 'data' and determine how much is function and how much is data so a function would be the brains 'capability' to recognize, and data is the specific object itself. So function is more or less genetically motivated "someone likes blue color while someone else likes red...". I wish I could have framed my question properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to say a number because memory and activity are intermixed. Activity induces long-term modifications in the brain wiring which can be considered as memory, but at the same time, those connections play functional roles.
For example, in the retina, the codification of the visual stimuli that are going to be transmitted to the brain is done by a network wiring that is somehow shaped by previous activity.
At an ontogenic level, we could think that the brain architecture in any specie is shaped by a phylogenetic memory during evolution.
Because of that, I'm tempted to respond 100%, but no rigorous answer can be done as far as I know.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for but I still need some clarification. I am interested in the reference for `the codification of the visual stimuli that are going to be transmitted to the brain is done by a network wiring that is somehow shaped by previous activity` Now I really want to separate out the evolutionary part from functionality part, the functionality of our brain is indeed encoded by external stimuli over the course of the evolution but "given the current state" of the encoded brain,  is there anyway to know how much of the brain is memory and how much function?

Comment: So for an analogy we can use evalutionary algorithms to shape hidden layers of artificial neural network, once we reach a satisfactory state, we get a function that although has been shaped by evolutionary algorithm (which relies on memory), is still a function and not memory, when this function is later used to train on some data, say image recognition, we acquire weights and biases which can be considered as memory as weights and biases may differ if one has to recognize certain person or a cat.

Comment: @gfdsal There is no difference between the memory and function. Memory is held in the synaptic weights in the connections between neurons; nervous system function involves patterns of activity which in turns are governed by those same weights.

Comment: @BryanKrause makes so much sense. Is there any mathematical model or even a general model of this. I want to see how exactly "pattern of activity" simulate a function and why our NN computational models are so bad and less robust against computational model of brain.

Comment: @gfdsal Neural networks and brains optimize completely different things, because things that are "easy" for biology to do are really hard to do in simulation, and some computations are really easy to do in silico but very expensive in real brains (for example, the distance between nodes matters in brains, it doesn't matter to any appreciable degree in silico). An adult human has almost 100 billion neurons each making thousands of synapses and trained over somewhere between 18 and 100 years.

Comment: @BryanKrause Do we know what exactly are these so-called things that brains optimize? Is there any model of such object. All I learned is that these synapse aggregate in similar fashion as neural nets, you are right that distance in hardware in silicon doesnt matter but we do utilize the notion of distance (more precisely inner product /norm) in the computational model which simulates the nearness of the entities/object being learn just like in the brain...so functionality is mimicked by computational model itself.

Comment: @gfdsal This is where I would stop and give the advice I have given numerous people trying to understand relationships between biological and artifical neural networks who are coming from the artificial side...If you want to compare them meaningfully, you need to be an expert in both. So, instead of starting with neural nets and looking for comparisons in biology, you need to start from the ground up in the biology and start learning the biology for its own sake. Then you can start to compare.

Comment: @BryanKrause acknowledge. Thanks for the advice.